I minted two tokens but cant see
I can see one in my wallet and the other does not show.  The amoo token does not show in
my wallet. Is a spl2022 token. The cat dog token shows but it does not appear on dex screeners.
https://solscan.io/account/FTM19FKvX3Bgfqu8ykmsxQ1a2ofwsPAkvGG8RzckyRxz
I am copying the contract address to add to birdeye and dextools and it says no data. So I want to finish the process so I can add liquidity and sell them. But I am stock.
